# Click on one div then appear below

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a kind of menu: a global div, inside 5 pictures to click and when you click on one, the content appear below, but all in the same area. Here is a picture (the content is hidden when no pictures are clicked).

http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/6359/divy.jpg

Here is what I've done, but without success:

http://jsfiddle.net/zL7Gn/

```
See code in jsfiddle
```

My problem is when you click on a picture, the content appear but all the other pictures are moved on the right...

Thanks a lot

Comment: try to clear your floats using a div: <div style="clear: both;"></div> or better in your css .clear { clear:both; } and <div class="clear"></div>

Comment: Doesn't work...
<div id="hideDetailsDiv" class="hideMe">
          <div class="clear">
                                        <div id="tinymce">
          <form method="post">
            <textarea></textarea>
          </form>
          </div>
                                        </div></div>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WfByx/

Comment: maybe you want the other elements to hide of the don't fit the window? I guess it works on a large screen. but in the jsfiddle it's to small.

Comment: Other verison, all is on one column now with clear:both: http://jsfiddle.net/rLm5T/

Comment: The real width of the main div is 547px, so it fits to jsfiddle window...

Comment: allright. so you just need something to hide them if the don't fit.

Comment: Don't know. overflow:hidden does not work.